# Railties is causing rails g not to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, clearance

When I try `rails g clearance:install` or `rails g sorcery:install` it fails and responds with:

```
/Users/superhappyfuntime/pikipik/config/initializers/devise.rb:3: uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:556
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:555
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:ininstance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:inrun_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:inrun_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in initialize!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:insend'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in method_missing'
    from /Users/superhappyfuntime/pikipik/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:inrequire_environment!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:22
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

How can I get it to work properly?

Comment: Railties is part of Rails. That's not where your problem is. There are two lines you should be looking at: The first, which tells you there's a problem with Devise (have you followed all of the instructions for setting up Devise?), and the fifth from the bottom that tells you the error originates in your app on line 5 of `config/environment.rb`. What's on line 5 and the lines around it?

Comment: @Jordan removing Devise fixed the issue.

Comment: What if Devise is what I'm wanting to use and I'm still getting this same exact error? I don't have any other auth gems installed.

Comment: @Marc try another gem like Sorcery, clearance, OAuth, Warden, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide closure of this question, Devise was somehow causing this issue.